# Regex to parse @user mentions

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

I have been using following Regex to parse @username from posts in my application.

```
'/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/
```

Can somebody explain me the purpose of `(^|\s)`. What if I omit that part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(^|\s)` either matches the beginning of a string (`^`) or a space character (`\s`). This is in order to prevent `hallo#world` from matching as a mention.

An alternative to that is using `\b` (a word boundary). It has slightly different semantics, but it should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`(^|\s)` is either the start of the line or string (`^`) or (`|`) a white space character (`\s`)